# SQLite and recursive triggers

Tags: sqlite, recursion, triggers

I want to understand exactly what is a recursive trigger. I of course know what recursion is, but, in the case of sqlite, are recursive trigger those which call itself?, or which call itself but only over the same rows? is in that definition included the case of indirect recursion? only over the same rows or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A recursive trigger is one which fires the same trigger, directly or indirectly, over the same rows or not.

The pragma command `recursive_triggers` controls if recursive triggers are enabled or not. By default they aren't (version 3.8.2).

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE example (a INTEGER);

CREATE TRIGGER example_1
AFTER UPDATE ON example WHEN NEW.a = 5 OR NEW.a = 6
BEGIN UPDATE example SET a = NEW.a + 1; END;

INSERT INTO example SELECT 1;
UPDATE example SET a = 5;
SELECT * FROM example; -- a = 6. Direct recursion forbidden.

PRAGMA recursive_triggers = ON;

UPDATE example SET a = 5;
SELECT * FROM example; -- a = 7. Direct recursion enabled.

DROP TRIGGER example_1;

PRAGMA recursive_triggers = OFF;

CREATE TRIGGER example_1
AFTER UPDATE ON example WHEN NEW.a = 5 OR NEW.a = 7
BEGIN UPDATE example SET a = NEW.a + 1; END;

CREATE TRIGGER example_2
AFTER UPDATE ON example WHEN NEW.a = 6
BEGIN UPDATE example SET a = NEW.a + 1; END;

UPDATE example SET a = 5;
SELECT * FROM example; -- a = 7. Indirect recursion forbidden.

PRAGMA recursive_triggers = ON;

UPDATE example SET a = 5;
SELECT * FROM example; -- a = 8. Indirect recursion enabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive trigger is a trigger whose execution causes *any* trigger to run (itself or any other trigger).

Comment: And what is a cascade trigger then?

Comment: That is a different question. Where did you find this term?

Comment: Different places (like linked questions here). Are you sure a recursive trigger is one which just calls other triggers?

Comment: That's what the SQLite documentation means with this term.